# How do I access a file on Windows with an invalid filename?

Tags: windows, ntfs, rename, filenames

I recovered a file using [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) from (I believe) a FAT32 file system to an NTFS file system with Windows 10 installed.  The file had a space in its name: `The Grilling` .  In Windows, I know that filenames with trailing spaces aren't allowed, but somehow Recuva created it anyway.  However, I can't rename or delete the file.  When I try to do so in Windows Explorer, I get an error:

[image: "Cannot find this item" error message]

I know it has a space in its name:

[image: Explorer with the file name selected, showing it has a trailing space]

I then tried to do rename it with the Command Prompt.  Tab completion reveals the file to have a trailing space, but it doesn't recognize the file:

```
C:\...>rename "The Grilling " "The Grilling-"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\...>rename "The Grilling" "The Grilling-"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\...>rename "\\.\\C:\\...\\The Grilling " "The Grilling-"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\...>rename "\\.\\C:\\...\\The Grilling" "The Grilling-"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can manipulate its parent folder, but I can't do anything to the file.  How can I rename the file so I can access or delete it?

Comment: Trailing spaces are not forbidden in NTFS. Try it out with a different file.

Comment: @r2d3 When the file has an extension, it works, but when I try it without an extension, it automatically removes the trailing space.

Comment: I am sorry. I tested it again and the trailing space is deleted. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: How long is your path to the file in question?

Comment: @r2d3 Do you mean `C:\Path\The Grilling `, `C:\Path\ ` (without the space, I just needed that for markdown to work) or `C:\Path`?

Comment: The whole Path including the file name.

Comment: @r2d3 66 characters.

Comment: This question is a bit ugly.. You're saying you want to access it and in the body of the question you say you want to delete it.  I hope nobody looks up how to recovery a file and sees the answer you accepted about deleting the file!

Comment: You boot off a linux thing

Comment: @barlop "You're saying you want to access it and in the body of the question you say you want to delete it." - I want to delete _and_ access it.  "I hope nobody looks up how to recovery a file and sees the answer you accepted about deleting the file!" - see the comments on the accepted answer and re-read it, it says how to both delete it and access it.

Comment: @Anonymous i'm not denying that. Technically to delete it you have to access it in some way. But when people speak of accessing they tend to not mean deleting! Also if a person follows the first part, they won't have a file to try to rename.

Comment: @barlop Then they can follow the second step and rename it, thus making them able to access it like any file... deletion is only optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the file's 8.3 name by using the `dir /x` command, then run `del`  followed by the file's 8.3 name to delete the file.

[image: Animated picture showing the process]

To rename (let's say the file is on the desktop and you want to rename it to `The Grilling.avi`):

```
ren "\\?\%userprofile%\desktop\The Grilling " "The Grilling.avi"
```

Comment: The `del` command works, but `ren` outputs `The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Comment: Ok I'm testing this...one moment please, (the del command works) so you don't have the file anymore? What was the file's original extension?

Comment: Correct.  I had 2 identical files, and I ran `del` on one of them.  It disappeared from Explorer, and as far as I can tell, it's been deleted.  I tried running `ren` on another, but it gave me that error.

Comment: please check my updated answer...to rename

Comment: Both commands work now, thank you.

Comment: No problemo, glad to help

Comment: You should clarify this. The question asks "How do I access a file on Windows with an invalid filename?"   The very first thing you  said will prevent access to the file, or make access to the file much harder, because you say he should run the DEL command, which as you afterwards say, deletes the file. The question body does mention deleting the file so is a bit schitzophrenic. I hope nobody looks up how to recovery a file and ends up deleting the file because of your post! thinking that deleting the file by its 8.3 name,  was helping them access the file in some way!

Comment: And suppose they don't want to delete it and they see that the first part of your answer is saying how to delete it. So they skip taht. And they look just at the renaming. You don't seem to be using the 8.3 name to rename. So what are they going t odo if the REN command doesn't work because it can't rename the file. Ultimately if windows struggles to reneame a file.. if unlocker or equivalent fails, then they can use a linux bootable usb.

Comment: If you use ren with the \\?\ part you don't need the 8.3 name. The topic creater asked both how to delete or rename so I posted both.