# In Windows I've managed to make a folder with the same name as another but with a space at the end. How can I access the contents of this folder?

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-11

This is Windows 11 Pro (22000.2057).

[image]

Using this code:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\Videos");
foreach (var sub in dir.GetDirectories())
{

    $"'{sub.Name}'".Dump();
}
```

I can see why:

[image]

Attempting to navigate through explorer shows the contents of "Movies" for both folders. Trying to navigate to it through powershell shows:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this help renaming the folder perhaps: https://superuser.com/a/1670640/705502

Comment: @JoepvanSteen No, but this answer did: https://superuser.com/a/911994/104427

Comment: ow, nice you got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the *entire path* does not end with a space – trailing spaces are technically valid for names but stripped from paths. When accessing the directory itself, suffix it with an additional `\`.

```
Videos\Movies \
```

If it were a file, you could suffix it with the explicit NTFS stream name `::$DATA`.